# How can I specify an arbitrary, bounded multivariate distribution?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I'm trying to fit a beta-binomial regression model and would like to specify the following prior on the parameters `a, b`:

```
p(a, b) ~ | (a + b)^(-5/2) if a > 0 and b > 0
          | 0 otherwise.
```

So far I have tried using `DensityDist` in the following way:

```
import pymc3 as mc

logp = lambda x: mc.switch(
    mc.and_(mc.gt(x[0], 0), mc.gt(x[1], 0)),
    -2.5 * mc.log(x[0] + x[1]),
    -np.inf)

ab = mc.DensityDist('ab', logp, shape=(2,), testval=(1, 1))
```

but defining the likelihood piecewise like this (understandably) causes problems with the numerical optimization in, e.g., `find_MAP`.

I've come across `Bounded`, which allows one to define bounded 1-d distributions, but haven't been able to figure out how to extend this to multivariate distributions. Is it possible to implement the above in an idiomatic way that plays nicely with numerical optimizations?

Comment: You could probably replace np.inf by a very large number. Then the probability distribution will still essentially the same, but the optimizers should still work fine.